# How can i get the common elements in the first two list and save to a new list in python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
list1 = [input("Enter the values for the first list: ")]
list2 = [input("Enter the values for the second list: ")]
print(list1)
print(list2)
list3 = []
for element in list1:
    if element in list2:
        list3 = list2.append(element)
print(list3)
```

This is what i have tried. but I am getting an empty list as list3!

Comment: Use `set`. `intersect` of two lists is the common! https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=set%20types#set

Comment: If you just use `[input()]`, your list will consist of a single string, which is probably not what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
list1 = [input("Enter the values for the first list: ")]
list2 = [input("Enter the values for the second list: ")]
```

list1 and list2 will be a list of string. hence you are getting list3 empty. PFB code and o/p:

```
list1 = [input("Enter the values for the first list: ")]
list2 = [input("Enter the values for the second list: ")]
print(list1)
print(list2)
list3 = []
for element in list1:
    print(type(element))
    if element in list2:
        list3.append(element)

print(list3)
```

output:

```
Enter the values for the first list: 1 2 3 4 5
Enter the values for the second list: 2 3 4 5 6 
['1 2 3 4 5']
['2 3 4 5 6']
<class 'str'>
[]
```

to add the correct way. Please see below eg. for getting list1 and list2:

```
# list1 = [input("Enter the values for the first list: ")]
# list2 = [input("Enter the values for the second list: ")]
list1 = [int(item) for item in input("Enter the 1st list items : ").split()]
list2 = [int(item) for item in input("Enter the 2nd list items : ").split()]

print('1st list: ',list1)
print('2nd list: ',list2)
list3 = []
for element in list1:
    if element in list2:
        list3.append(element)

print('common: ', list3)
```

output:

```
Enter the 1st list items : 1 2 3 4 5
Enter the 2nd list items : 3 4 5 6 7
1st list:  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
2nd list:  [3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
common:  [3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: That split() function was empty. so I had to use a separator inside that and it worked perfectly. Thanks for the help buddy.

Comment: @Python_beginner i entered the input as space separator, so for split method default separator is any whitespace. if you give any other separator in input,  You can specify the separator. if this solves your question, you can accept that as an answer and upvote please :)

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `[input('Enter numbers: ')]` to get the numbers for a list. This will create a list containing the input string. What you really have to do is first take input for numbers in a variable, lets say `list1_inp` and then split `list1_inp` based on spaces using `nums = list1_inp.split(' ')`. Now you can iterate through your list checking for common elements.

```
list1_inp = input('Enter the elements separated by spaces : ')
nums = list1_inp.split()
list2_inp = input('Enter the elements separated by spaces : ')
nums2 = list2_inp.split()

temp = nums2
final = []
for elem in nums:
   if elem in temp:
      final.append(elem)
      temp.remove(elem)

print(final)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mylist1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
mylist2 = [2,3,4,5,6] # let these be the two lists


def func():
    mylist3 = []  # This is the list where the common numbers append
    for x in mylist1:
        for y in mylist2:
            if x==y:
                mylist3.append(x)
            else:
                pass
return mylist3
```